# competing offers

Tags: negotiation

I have two offers on the table. One for a company I don't necessarily want to work for but pays more (company A) and one for a company I would really like to work for, but for significantly less (company B). B is willing to negoatiate and asked for a list of reasons why I deserve to make more than the minimum pay. One of the reasons listed is the higher offer at company A.

I told company B the approximate dollar amount of A and now B wants me to have A put the offer amount in writing and send them a copy?

Is that even a legal thing to ask?

Comment: Frankly I think you're talking too much. There's no reason why A or B need to know anything about each other. You might think it gives you leverage but it really doesn't because would they rather hire someone who is confident they are worth X because of their skill-set or would they rather hire someone with a proven track record of playing one against the other. However given the situation you are in, I would now simply tell B the minimum you will accept at this time to join them, simply ignore their request and leave the ball in their court.

Comment: Note: neither company has an offer on the table, because neither offer is in writing. You need to get one of them to give you a written offer

Comment: Ditto to @BradThomas - keep your cards close to your chest. If I was representing Company B, I'd probably have told you: "Fine, go work for Company A". If you think you deserve more, explain why- **done**. As it is, after Company B's response "Show me in writing..." IMO you'll probably be better off at Company A...

Answer (score 2):

> Is that even a legal thing to ask?

While it's perfectly legal for company B to ask you to get company A's offer in writing and show it to them, it would be an odd thing for them to ask. Perhaps they simply don't believe you, or perhaps they wonder if their own offer is far from market value.

Of course you are under absolutely no obligation to comply with their request. Certainly they know that.

You could just say "No", and deal with whatever is their response.

Or, if you are up to it, you could take the stakes a bit higher. Ask them if they will match company A's written offer if you go through all the trouble of getting it in writing.

If they say "Yes", then speak to company A, ask for the offer in writing, and sign on with company B at the company A rate.

If they say "No", then don't bother. Just negotiate as you will with both companies, and make your choice.